# How can I parse out the first three words from a string?

Tags: c#

I have this string:

```
var a = "a new test string today";
```

How can I parse a to make another string that contains just the words

```
"a new test"
```

Comment: Just split and take: `a.Split(' ').Take(3);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this in a number of ways.

For example: Using Split, LINQ and Join

```
string.Join(" ", a.Split(' ').Take(3));
```

Or by finding the third space:

```
var firstSpace = a.IndexOf(' ');
var secondSpace = a.IndexOf(' ', firstSpace + 1);
var thirdSpace = a.IndexOf(' ', secondSpace + 1);
result = a.Substring(0, thirdSpace);
```

Error handling omitted.